# What is the easiest way to make Azure pipeline stage fail for debugging purposes

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I would like to make a given stage fail to test my conditions

```
- stage: EnvironmentDeploy
  condition: and(succeeded()...)
```

is it possible to make `- stage` to fail purposefully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is adding a job with a [PowerShell script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-pwsh?view=azure-pipelines), and using the [`throw` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_throw?view=powershell-7.3) to exit the script with an error:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: StageToFail
  jobs:
  - job: JobToFail
    steps:
    - pwsh: throw "Throwing error for debugging purposes"
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want this fail to happen consistently as that would make deployment impossible. Assuming it's a one-off thing, why not try to upload code with compile errors so the build fails or - if your code base has them and your pipeline checks them as a prerequisite for deployment - add a unit test that fails.

Comment: I assume this is why he included a "condition" example in the question; He does NOT want this to happen consistently, but conditionally.